# How do I create an attribute table in a web page from GeoServer using JavaScript?

Tags: geoserver, leaflet, sql

I'm trying to create a custom web application using Leaflet and Geoserver. I've got my layers visible in a map viewer, but I'd also like to show an attribute table of the visible map layers. I can't seem to figure this out.

I tried going this route:

```js
var url = "http://serveraddress/geoserver/store/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=store:layer&outputFormat=text/javascript&format_options=callback:processJSON”";

    $.ajax({
        jsonp: false,
        jsonpCallback: 'processJSON”',
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        async: false,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data) {
           // useMyJson(data); 
        }
    });
```

But it just crashes my browser, probably from data overload...

Any ideas?

Comment: If you make the query directly in the browser, what sort of quantity of data do you get back? That at least should indicate if size is the problem.

Comment: 252408 features... anyways, I just changed the code to $.get(url2, function(responseText) {}) and used &maxFeatures and it worked!